# Install gstfft for gstreamer-1.0 in Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: raspbian

I have a Raspberry Pi 2 with Raspbian. I ran the following commands to have it updated:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

sudo reboot

sudo apt-get install gstreamer-1.0
sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-tools
```

I want to use and learn about the gstfft plugin for GStreamer...

http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-base-libs/html/gstreamer-ffft.html

The problem is that gst-inspect-1.0 will not find the plugin, even if the /usr/lib directory already has the SO files...

```
pi@pi2:/usr/lib$ find -name *gstfft*
./arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgstfft-0.10.so.0.25.0
./arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgstfft-1.0.so.0.200.0
./arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgstfft-1.0.so.0
./arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgstfft-0.10.so.0

pi@pi2:/usr/lib$ gst-inspect-1.0 | grep fft
pi@pi2:/usr/lib$
```

Could somebody please tell me what I am missing?

```
pi@pi2:/usr/lib$ gst-launch-1.0 fakesrc ! gstfft ! fakesink
WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "gstfft"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

gstreamer has several addition libraries which makes the process of figuring out what exactly you a "where is waldo" game. All the following test were ran on my Pi 3 having the same libraries installed as you.

As long as you have correctly installed gstreamer1.0, the fft file will exist.
the location of the header file for fft, I have found, is in:

> /usr/include/gstreamer-1.0/gst/fft/

(I used "find -iname gstfft" in the root)
But it is only a header file and is probably only used as a library.

When I look for the Plug-in with command:

> gst-inspect-1.0 gstfft

it returns that there is no such element or plug-in.

You will want to use the [spectrum](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good-plugins/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-plugin-spectrum.html) plugin, which "Run an FFT on the audio signal, output spectrum data"

Hope this helps you in future situations, sorry if this is not what you are looking for. If you would like addition plugins, they can be found on github or the site.